# Trying to post a form using Ninja Forms, on Wordpress, via Wamp Server on local intranet

Tags: wamp, ninja-forms

I cannot be more specific than the actual question. Happy to give versions of Wamp Server / Wordpress / Ninja Forms.

Bottom line, it's just not posting. I get the "thank you" page but no emails are ever received. There is no mail server set up on the local server.

Not sure what to do here really. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a local mailserver? Ninja forms need a mailserver to submit emails. If you don't have an smtp-server on your local machine. You need to install a local email test server.

Good luck ; )